# Django: Ajax Foreign Key's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Django(v2.2.3), Postgres(latest) and Chrome for browser.

I'm trying to reproduce some functionality of the Django administration interface in my own frontend application. So I have models that I create using a modal. Except that for linked models I invoke a popup if the linked model does not exist and I create it in the popup. The models are created normally and saved in the database. The main problem is that when the popup closes the new item created is not selected, let alone in the list of objects available in my selection

Example with image: Firstly i pushed link

enter image description here

When i get the modal i click on add button

enter image description here

I get first popup

enter image description here

Inside my popup i push another + button to add element if not exist

enter image description here

After Submitting inside another popup my select is not update: enter image description here

Example views:

I dont know what is wrong ????

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try to use jquery.

What you can do is assign a event on form submit.
Open the modal 1 there using:
`$('#modal-id').modal('show');`

similarly for else also

hope this helps!

Comment: Actually its a good idea to use Jquery for such case. Thanks for the help!